# Multiplex several TCP connections over a single tcp connection

Tags: c, windows, sockets, ssh, tcp

I'm building a client-server program that has the client and server connected using a single TCP connection.

Within the communication there are several data "channels", which I want to multiplex over my single TCP connection, while still having good flow-control between the channels (preventing starvation and so on...). Also, tunneling will be nice, but not a requirement.

I'm using C, Windows.

I thought of using ssh but I have several problems with it:

1. I had trouble finding a nice open-source ssh code for windows.
2. Most of the code in SSH handles security, which I have no need for.
3. SSH seems a little too complicated for my needs, with all the X11, pty, shells and so on.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you'd want to send data in "segments", where each segment would have a header giving the channel and number of bytes of data to follow. That way, you could intersperse data for the various channels on a single connection. Does that help?

Comment: You are right, but I prefer not to implement it by myself, including the dynamic allocation of channels and flow control to keep all of the channels flowing.